# Run Spark on YARN without spark-submit but with java

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

In a HDP 2.4 Hadoop cluster, with YARN, I am wondering if it's possible to run a Java Apache Spark program without use `spark-submit --master=yarn` program, but by the Java directly? (or if it's really a bad practice).

My use case is to have a Java daemon, that bring a HTTP API to execute Spark job on different HDP clusters.

Comment: Take a look at the source for spark-submit, it doesnt do anything fancy, so yes you could avoid using it if you wanted to: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/bin/spark-submit

Comment: @RyanS AFAIK that's not exactly true. There are known bugs (you'll have to search JIRA, as I don't recall specific issues), which are related to running Spark outside `spark-submit`. As far as I remember these were closed as not a problem (with note - not supported).

Comment: Try to think of spark launcher and see whether your problem will be solved. https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-SparkLauncher.html